# I have a problem with adding node to doubly linked list tail

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to write a program about a doubly linked list using templates.

All functions work correctly except the one that adds a node to the end of the list (add_tail). When compiling, despite adding values to the "tail" in a small selection menu that I made - they do not show up when displaying the full list.

Below is my code, it does not have any errors and compiles without problems (at least visual studio does not show them).

I am unable to determine what is causing this problem. Please help me and thank you very much in advance for it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node {
private:
    T dane;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node<T>* prev;
    template <typename U>
    friend class linked_list;

public:
    Node() {
        this->next = nullptr;
        this->prev = nullptr;
    }
};
template <typename T>
class linked_list {
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
public:
    linked_list() { 
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
    }
    void add_tail(T element) {
        Node<T>* node = new Node<T>[1];
        node->dane = element;
        if (tail == nullptr) {
            tail = node;
            cout << "dodano nowy element" << endl;
            return;
        }
        Node<T>* temp = tail;
        Node<T>* prev{};
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = node;
        temp->prev = prev;
        cout << "dodano nowy element na koncu" << endl;
    }
    void add_head(T element) {
        Node<T>* node = new Node<T>[1];
        node->dane = element;
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = node;
            cout << "dodano nowy element z przodu" << endl;
            return;
        }
        head->next = head;
        head->prev = node;
        head = node;
        cout << "dodano nowy element z przodu" << endl;
    }
    void del_tail() {
        if (tail == nullptr) {
            cout << "lista jest pusta" << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (tail->next == nullptr) {
            head = nullptr;
            cout << "usunieto ostatni element" << endl;
            return;
        }
        Node<T>* temp = tail;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            if (temp->next->next == nullptr) {
                temp->next = nullptr;
                cout << "usunieto ostatni element" << endl;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    void del_head() {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            cout << "lista jest pusta" << endl;
            return;
        }
        head = head->next;
        head->next->prev = head;
        cout << "usunieto pierwszy element" << endl;
    }
    void del_all() {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>[1];
        while (head != nullptr) {
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            //free(temp);
            delete[] temp;
        }
        cout << "Lista wyczyszczona pomylnie" << endl;
    }
    void dis_all() {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            cout << "lista jest pusta" << endl;
            return;
        }
        cout << endl << "wszystkie elementy listy:" << endl;
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            cout << temp->dane << " | ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl << "-------------------------" << endl;
    }
    void search_ele(T searchElement) {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        int found = 0;
        int i = 0;
        if (temp != nullptr) {
            while (temp != nullptr) {
                i++;
                if (temp->dane == searchElement) {
                    found++;
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (found == 1) {
                cout << searchElement << " zostala znaleziona na indeksie = " << i << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << searchElement << " nie znajduje sie na liscie." << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "lista jest pusta." << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    linked_list<int> list;
    int element, zn, searchElement;
    bool quit = false;
    do {
        cout << "----------MENU WYBORU----------" << endl;
        cout << "Wybierz opcje:" << endl;
        cout << "1: dodanie nowego elementu na koncu listy" << endl;
        cout << "2: dodanie nowego elementu na poczatku listy" << endl;
        cout << "3: usuniecie ostatniego elementu" << endl;
        cout << "4: usuniecie pierwszego elementu" << endl;
        cout << "5: wyszukanie elementu" << endl;
        cout << "6: czyszczenie listy" << endl;
        cout << "7: wyswietlenie listy" << endl;
        cout << "8: wyjscie" << endl;
        cin >> zn;
        switch (zn) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Wybierz element do dodania:" << endl;
            cin >> element;
            list.add_tail(element);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Wybierz element do dodania:" << endl;
            cin >> element;
            list.add_head(element);
            break;
        case 3:
            list.del_tail();
            break;
        case 4:
            list.del_head();
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Wybierz element do znalezienia:" << endl;
            cin >> searchElement;
            list.search_ele(searchElement);
            break;
        case 6:
            list.del_all();
            break;
        case 7:
            list.dis_all();
            break;
        case 8:
            quit = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Zly wybor" << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (!quit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: in a doubly linked list, as you have here, do you not need to walk the list in order to insert a new tail element. You have the prior tail element (if the list is not empty). Set the new node's prev to the previous tail, then set tail to the new node. You need to patch up the forward links also, of course.

Comment: Please provide example of input. Note currently tool finds memory leak: https://godbolt.org/z/McfMbxE7Y also result for given input is invalid (content of list is `3` and suppose to be `3 8`

Comment: `Node<T>* node = new Node<T>[1];` WAT? Array of size one?

Comment: *"All functions work correctly"* - that isn't true at all. You really need to get a piece of paper, a pencil, and start drawing some boxes/arrows, step by step, to examine how your code works. Ex: `head->next = head;` is a recipe for instant orphanage and leaking of your entire previous list in your `add_head` function. Worse, it creates a circular list-of-one. Stop coding and start drawing.

Comment: @MarekR already changed that to `Node<T>* node = new Node<T>();` :D

Answer (score 0):

When adding the tail element, you have to set node->prev to temp and not temp->prev to prev (it is already set to prev)